# Why does an unitialized typed variable in Dart not implement the type's interface?

Tags: dart

I started learning Dart and was reading a critique of some of it's design choices here: https://medium.com/@krossovochkin/dart-language-bad-design-choices-6e35987dc693

The last point that is made is about the poor type system and the author cited this code snippet which prints `null`:

```
void main() {
  String s = null;
  if (s is String) {
    print("string");
  } else if (s is Null) {
    print("null");
  } else {
    print ("none");
  }
}
```

The `is` keyword was new to me but "The Dart Programming Language" by Gilad pointed out that `is` checks the interface implemented by an object's class and not the actual class of an object.

However this didn't help me much because I would think that the variable `s` is an instance of `String` and therefore implements `String`, but the evidence is to the contrary.

I get that the class is not required when defining objects/variables in Dart, and thus I started to wonder if putting the class in the definition just serves as sugar and has little functional purpose. But instead the class of an object/variable is completely determined by its value, and since the default value for all variables in Dart is `null`, then it would make sense that `String` is not implemented, but `Null` is. Is this the case? Am I way of base? Maybe someone could help me wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `is` checks the interface of the current object itself and not the reference to this object. So yes, `s` can point to a `String` object but also allowed to point to null which are a instance of `Null`: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/Null-class.html

Since `Null` does not implement the `String` interface, this will return false `(null is String)`. This is also mentioned in the article.

The problem the article are trying to focus on are more the fact you are allowed to set the `String` variable to `null` value but `Null` does not implement `String`.

Well, in the future, this problem are going to be fixed with non-nullable types which are in development right now. When this is implemented you can actually define variables where you can be sure the value will never be `null`.

Comment: Ah I see, that clears it up for me. My theory of it checking the interface of the actual `value`  was not wholly incorrect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I continued my Dart reading and I came to a better understanding, and that is that Dart is truly optionally typed and that means 2 things:

1. Type are syntactically optional.
2. Type has no impact on runtime semantics.

Therefore the actual type annotation of a variable in Dart only serves documentation purposes and it cannot be assumed that a type annotation is true. The actual type of a variable is wholly determined by the value stored at this variable, and in this case it is `null`.

In truth the variable that I defined in my example is not a `String` variable or an implementer of the `String` interface. It is just annotated that it may be/should be/most likely is a string.